# Remove anonymous users in MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, lamp

I'm getting this error

```
Remove anonymous users? [Y/n] y
ERROR 1142 (42000) at line 1: DELETE command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'user'
 ... Failed!
1 at /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation line 224, <STDIN> line 3.
Cleaning up...
```

While trying to reset MySQL settings, also I log into shell with root, any thoughts?

Comment: Add the command you used to get there.  Or is this done via PHPMyAdmin?  Details please.

Comment: well I run this command `sudo mysql_secure_installation` and entered my password and when I get to remove the anonymous users it gives me that error.